# Jquery unobtrusive doesn't show the validation message for checkbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, unobtrusive-validation

I have a checkbox element like below

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="You must accept our terms and conditions." id="Terms" name="Terms" required="required" type="checkbox" value="true">
```

The problem is when the checkbox is not checked. instead of `You must accept our terms and conditions.` it renders `This field is required.` while all the other fields work the way they should.

Are there any extra attributes that I need to add to the element?

Comment: Perhaps mention ASP and tag the question more appropriately.  This has far more to do with how to use and configure Unobtrusive Validation as part of your ASP project than anything else.   If you were simply using the jQuery Validate plugin by itself, there would be an entirely different solution.

Comment: @Sparky I'm not using ASP.Net helper methods. although this is generated in a cshtml file the creation of the tag is manual except the validation messages come from the backend.

Comment: If the validation messages come from the back end, then none of this would have anything to do with the client-side JavaScript plug-ins.